# I want to set state based on accessToken of cookies, but I can't access to cookies

Tags: cookies, setstate

I am using React and I want to access to cookies, specifically accessToken, so that I can setLogin(true) based on existence of accessToken.

I tried document.cookies, react-cookies library, but I can't access to that cookies...

[image]

even though I can see cookies on the browser,
whenever I console.log(cookies) like below, there is empty.

1. When I used document.cookie

[image];

2. When I used react-cookies

[image]

[image]

and cors Options are like below

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH']
  })
);
```

How can I know there is cookie[accessToken] and

How can I use setLogin(true) based on accessToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `accesstoken` is an `httpOnly` cookie. The `httpOnly` flag ensures that the cookie cannot be accessed by client-side javascript.

You can disable the `httpOly` flag on the `accesstoken` to make it accessible.

An alternative is getting the access token from the API and setting it in `localstorage`, which is the most common I've seen.

You can try and search online on how to store `accesstoken` in react app